# Will `nodetool rebuild` truncate the tables before it starts to stream?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

Will `nodetool rebuild` truncate the tables before it starts to stream? Or will I need to empty the data directory first I've I'd like to reset the data on a node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `rebuild` will just stream the data. You would need to truncate the data yourself first.